# How to save log file to external storage in android

Tags: java, android

I want to save some logs generated automatically to external storage in Android using java as a txt file, I created menu item like a button, [The image used for external button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMWXK.png)

This is the xml code used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/export_item"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_set_as"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/export"
```

```
 app:showAsAction="always" />
```

```
 public static void SaveToExternalStorage(String filename) {
        What code should I use?
    }
```

Comment: What exactly did you `try` to save the logs on the device?

Comment: some txt logs like , "2021.02.04 - App started"